# javascript newwindow.document.getElementById sometimes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, settimeout, getelementbyid, window.open

I am trying to access elements on a newly opened window(window.open), and then change its style.display property to make it visible. I have tried different versions, but in my best version it only works some of the time. It seems to be affected by the number of other things that are processing, because when I open a third window it takes very long and doesn't work. Sometimes it doesn't even work for the first opened window.

```
    var poppy=null;
    function openAlf(anch,id) {
    poppy=window.open("http://mrsbos.wikispaces.com/Alphabetical+Code+list#"+id,
    "_blank"," width=550, height=600, left=500,top=0");

    setTimeout(showEl,1000);

     }

    function showEl(){

    poppy.document.getElementById('area000t').style.display="block";
    }
```

In another version I pass the area_id to the showEl function.That one does not work either, which is a shame because I need to be able to open different elements with the openAlf() function. I think it is a time thing. Does anyone know what I can do about it?

Or is there a way I can read the elements from the Alphabetical page, without opening it and than writing them to a new window with window.open and mywindow.write

Comment: Maybe could you try to call showEl on the poppy.document.ready event ? Furthermore, be sure your ID begins with a letter [a-z], and is unique in the web page. If those 3 steps don't show you the issue, I dunno..

Answer (score 0):

```
      var poppy=null;




      function openAlf(anch,id) {
        poppy=window.open("http://mrsbos.wikispaces.com/Alphabetical+Code+list",
       "_blank"," width=550, height=600, scrollbars=yes,left=500,top=0");

      readyState=setTimeout(function(){checker(id) },1000);
       }

      function checker(id){
      console.log("checker");
      try{
      console.log("try");

      poppy.document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";
      clearInterval(readyState);
       }

       catch(err){
       console.log("catch");
       readyState=setTimeout(function(){checker(id) },1000);
       }
       }
```

This solution worked